# iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch 2020) RAM Upgrade

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I purchased and installed  4x32GB of RAM (*OWC2666DR4S128S*) in my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch 2020) RAM. It works.

I noticed that neither Manufacturer nor Part Number are detected when I inspect and wondered if this is a function of my installation or the OWC2666DR4S128S or just MacOSX.

Should MacOSX be able to identify the Manufacturer and Part Number from *OWC2666DR4S128S*?

And do I need to reinstall the memory if it indicates that it is not done well?

[image]

I also ran this (per response from @pion)

```
ioreg -p IODeviceTree -n memory -r
```

and returned

```
+-o memory  <class IOService, id 0x100000162, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 4>
    {
      "dimm-part-number" = <00000000>
      "dimm-types" = <"DDR4","DDR4","DDR4","DDR4">
      "slot-names" = <"   ","Slot 2 (Channel A / DIMM 0)","Slot 1 (Channel A / DIMM 1)","Slot 4 (Channel B / DIMM 0)","Slot 3 (Channel B / DIMM 1)">
      "dimm-speeds" = <"2667 MHz","2667 MHz","2667 MHz","2667 MHz">
      "dimm-manufacturer" = <"0000","0000","0000","0000">
      "ecc-enabled" = No
      "reg" = <0800000000000000080000000000000008000000000000000800000000000000>
      "dimm-info" = <0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
      "dimm-serial-number" = <"F50A01D5","20480953","20450132","10D30000">
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Manufacturer` and `Part Number` fields on a DRAM module are stored on an EEPROM chip on the module and transmitted to the CPU using the [**Serial Presence Detect (SPD)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) protocol. SPD information is read by **[firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)** at system boot time and that information is then handed over to the OS using **[ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)**. macOS's **[xnu](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu)** kernel stores and publishes ACPI data using **[IORegistry](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/TheRegistry/TheRegistry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000014-TP9)**.

*System Profiler* reads ACPI data via IORegistry's `IODeviceTree` plane. You can view all the published properties of your DRAM with the following command:

```
ioreg -p IODeviceTree -n memory -r
```

Whatever strings are stored in the `dimm-manufacturer` and `dimm-part-number` fields here will be the same as those shown by `System Profiler`.

If these fields are missing or have `0` / `Unknown` values, this may be either:

1. The result of that SPD data being absent from the EEPROM, in which case it is the **manufacturer's fault**; or
2. Due to a bug in the firmware's platform-dependent **[memory reference code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Reference_Code)**, which is specific to a particular Mac hardware product version (e.g., `iMac20,1` in your case) and often contains bugs that are specific to just that product version due to the proportionally lower amount of testing and engineering exposure that any given product version gets relative to the entire family. In this case it would be **Apple's fault**.

A way to discern between (1) and (2) would be to install the same DRAM in another system that is compatible with that kind of DRAM but which is not an `iMac20,1`. If you see valid values, then it's Apple's bug and should be **[reported to them](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)**. If not, **[reach out to OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/Service/)** and see if this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I have already reached out to OWC to ask if this is expected behavior too.